# Can I have multiple twitter oauth callback urls

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I have created a Twitter application and specified the following url as the callback url:

http://www.myapp.com/login

However, when a user comes to my site from the url myapp.com (missing the www prefix) the authentication fails.

Apparently, I cannot have multiple urls. So what can be a workaround?

Comment: Gotta love the twitter oauth.. wasted a few days on their quirks. All other providers worked out of the box except twitter. And as soon as you think you got it all working and figured out it's a *knock, knock, whoisit, twitter quirk* situation all over again.. facepalm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either

1. Feed the correct OAuth URL by changing it based on the hostname the user uses to access your app.
2. Implement a canonical domain name, making sure visitors are redirected to the www version (or vice versa).

No, you cannot feed multiple URLs to the OAuth service.

Comment: Sorry for the novice question but how do I detect the hostname the user uses to access my app?

Comment: For that we need to know the language/platform you are running on. In general terms, access the request object and get the host name from the properties there.

Comment: Yup, I was about to try this. I am using Tornado and Python